# adb uiautomator get all of the scrollable content

Tags: adb

When getting the current UI elements displayed on the screen using `adb exec-out uiautomator dump`, only the visible elements are included in the xml. I want to get all of the elements that are present in the scrollable view.
**Is there a way to get all of the content in the current Activity instead of only what is visible in the screen using adb uiautomator?**

For example in this image:
[image: First image showing top part of the Activity]

When the UI is dumped, only elements till end of the first paragraph ("adipiscing commodo") are extracted.

If I scroll down and dump the UI again in this state:
[image: Second image showing lower part of the Activity]
The content of second paragraph is also added in the UI dump.

How to get all of the content present in the current Activity?

Additional finding:
I can get of all text in the chat in the  Google Message app, even the messages not currently visible. Maybe it is a webpage thing. But also cannot get all the elements on the store page of an app in the PlayStore.